# django SearchFilter is not filtering the list of queryset,it returns all of it

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, filtering

this is my view views.py file

```
class StudentList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Student.objects.all()
serializer_class = StudentSerializer
#pagination_class = StudentPageNumberPagination
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
search_fields=['name','mobile']
```

this is my serializers class

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Student
    fields=('id','name','mobile','time','late','date')
```

this is what i type in browser

http://192.168.0.118:8000/students/?name=ket

and i get all of items in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SearchFilter your search string must be passed in search parameter, like this:
http://192.168.0.118:8000/students/?search=ket
You can read about it in [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter). If you want to split your query parameters into specific fields you can use [DjangoFilterBackend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) instead of SearchFilter.